# ¿Por qué al usar SQLBulkCopy la información no se migra en el mismo orden?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, asp.net-web-api

**Transfondo**

Estoy desarrollando un servicio usando Web API. Este servicio recibe un arreglo de `bytes` **que es la representación de un archivo Excel**, el cual posee hasta 40 columnas y puede llegar a tener mas de 40000 registros.

Utilizo el siguiente código para obtener la información del archivo Excel **luego de haber obtenido el arreglo de bytes y convertirlo**:

```
// Conectar con el archivo creado en pasos anteriores.
using (OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(cadenaConexion))
{
    objConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    string sheetName = string.Empty;

    if (dt != null)
    {
        var tempDataTable = (from dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             where !dataRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Contains("FilterDatabase")
                             select dataRow).CopyToDataTable();
        dt = tempDataTable;
        sheetName = dt.Rows[TABLE_ROW]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    }

    cmd.Connection = objConn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
    oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    oleda.Fill(ds, nombreTabla);
    tbl_temporal = ds.Tables[nombreTabla];
    objConn.Close();
}
```

Al consultar la variable `tbl_temporal` - que es la variable que posee la información obtenida del Excel - ésta posee su información en un orden diferente comparado con el archivo Excel seleccionado.

Utilizo este código para enviar toda la información de la variable `tbl_temporal` a la tabla de **SQL Server 2014**:

```
// BulkCopy the data in the DataTable to the temp table.
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulk
    = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(connString))
{
    bulk.BulkCopyTimeout = 300;
    bulk.DestinationTableName = tbl_temporal.TableName;
    bulk.WriteToServer(tbl_temporal);
}
```

**Inquietudes**

> ¿Es posible utilizar otra forma para obtener la información del archivo Excel y que la información mantenga el mismo orden de la información?

Mientras redactaba esta pregunta, pensé que se debía al **SQLBulkCopy**, pero creo que realmente el problema está en el código que uso para obtener la información del Excel.

---

La estructura de la tabla en mi base de datos es la siguiente:

```
USE [miBaseDatos]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Facts](
    [FileID] [int] NOT NULL, -- Esta columna NO existe en el Excel.
    [Company] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Entry No#] [float] NULL,
    [G/L Account No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Hyperion Nø] [float] NULL,
    [GL Account Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Posting Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Document Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Document No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Global Dimension 1 Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Global Dimension 2 Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [User ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Source Code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Debit Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Credit Amount] [float] NULL,
    [Document Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [External Document No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [No# Series] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Document Source] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [On Behalf Customer No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [On Behalf VAT Registration No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [VAT Registration No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [VAT Ref] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Job No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Job Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Media Campagin No#] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Brand Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Brand Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [On Behalf] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Dim# City] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Customer Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Dim# Divison] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Dim# Subdivision] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Third Party Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [x] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Terceros] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [HYP CLIENT] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [CSA] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Estas son las cadenas de conexión que el desarrollo utiliza.
Esta solución es una aplicación WebAPI - Entity Framework:

Web.config:

```
<add name="connString_MiProyecto" connectionString="Data Source=amazonas;Initial Catalog=MiProyecto;User ID=userDB;Password=PassDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

App.config:

```
<add name="MiProyectoEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MiProyectoDB.csdl|res://*/MiProyectoDB.ssdl|res://*/MiProyectoDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=amazonas;initial catalog=MiProyecto;persist security info=True;user id=userDB;password=PassDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Cadena de conexión "Excel":

```
string excelConnString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + rutaArchivo + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;';";
```

Comment: ¿En tu archivo de Excel tienes un orden? A lo que voy es que si existe algún campo con el se puede tomar de referencia para que una vez que tengas el Excel en memoria se pueda ordenar más adelante. Ago así `.....CopyToDataTable().OrdeBy(t => t.CampoDeReferecia)`

Comment: @Flxtr, no, los usuarios suben el excel, no hay un campo de referencia *(por ahora, ya que este es un desarrollo en progreso)*.

Comment: Tal vez no sea relevante, pero podrías poner la cadena de conexion?

Comment: @Pikoh pregunta actualizada.

Comment: Has probado lo que pone en [esta respuesta?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36509770/579895) Por otro lado,para descartar que no sea al obtener los datos del excel,depura el codigo y mira que tiene el datatable tras el `Fill`

Comment: Por favor aclárame el proceso. 1. Recibes un arreglo de bytes y lo conviertes a un archivo de excel en el servidor. Correcto ? 2.Verificaste que al crearlo en el servidor corresponda exactamente en orden al que creas en el servidor? 3. Te sugiero para simplificar trabajar con csv y hacer bulkinsert en sql server, es mucho más rápido, robusto y en cuanto a la implementación mucho más sencillo.

Comment: @JorgeLondoño, la verdad no he revisado si el archivo Excel creado en el servidor está en el mismo orden que el archivo "original". Me gustaría ver una respuesta acerca de cómo usarías el BulkInsert.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer tienes un error de entendimiento acerca de como se muestra la información en una base de datos, es decir, como determinas que tu orden está incorrecto con respecto al orden en el excel, entiendo que haciendo "una consulta" (select * from...).

El orden de la información de la base de datos (mediante una consulta) se presenta teniendo en cuenta la cláusula order by. Si esta no está presente, el motor de base de datos decidirá como ordenar la información en la consulta, dependiendo de los índices entre otros factores.

Cuando tu haces un select sin order by en una tabla cualquiera, esta se representa, por ejemplo para tu caso puntual, en el sql management (por poner un ejemplo) en un orden determinado por los factores que antes mencioné, sin embargo eso lo decidió el motor, por eso cuando necesites tener un orden específico debes aplicar order by.

Sugiero sepas el criterio de ordenamiento para poder aplicarle una cláusula order by a la consulta que te esté mostrando la información para que se presente de la misma manera que la tienes en el excel.

**Actualización:** Te recomiendo hacer una columna id de secuencia en el excel que te ayudará a representar la información como se muestra en excel mediante esa columna en una consulta sql.

Comment: Creo que no entiendo lo que dices en el primer párrafo, pero, se que no tiene el mismo orden porque comparo tanto el archivo como la consulta a la tabla en la base de datos "sin usar la cláusula ORDER BY"; ejemplo `SELECT * FROM Facts` el orden no es el mismo y no he aplicado en otras partes del programa esta cláusula. Es difícil definir un criterio de ordenamiento ya que existen otras reglas que se deben aplicar a la información a pasar a la base de datos - fuera del alcance de esta pregunta *(así de complejo es)* :)

Comment: si no usas order by, no puedes garantizar en que orden se presente la información, así de sencillo es. independientemente de lo fácil o difícil que sea aplicar un criterio de ordenamiento, 'debes' hacerlo si quieres presentar la información de cierta manera.

Answer (score -1):

SqlBulkCopy si carga los datos tal cual están en tu archivo Excel, lo que pasa es que no le estás especificando a SQL como quieres que te muestre los datos, y la verdad es un misterio como decide mostrartelos. Pero puedes agregar una columna Identity a la tabla donde cargas los datos, para que sepas que número de registro es el que insertó aunque la información no se muestra en el órden tal cual está en tu archivo Excel, y cuando hagas tu select puedes ponerle como Order by la columna que agregaste para que te muestre los datos tal cual están en tu archivo de Excel.

Por ejemplo:
SELECT * FROM [TableName] Order by Fila_Excel

Saludos :)

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.