# Convertir valor numérico a nvarchar en SQL Server no retorna valor esperado

Tags: sql-server

En SQL Server 2014 Management Studio tengo una consulta hacia una tabla, la cual contiene la columna "EntryNo" cuyo tipo de dato es `FLOAT`.

Menciono *SQL Server 2014 Management Studio* pero la respuesta aceptada debe funcionar con versiones anteriores. Ejemplo *SQL Server 2008 R2*.

Ejemplo:

Tabla: **DetalleDocumento**

```
| EntryNo |
-----------
| 2435864 |
```

Necesito retornar el valor de la columna "EntryNo" a `NVARCHAR(50)` sin que -por ahora- tenga que cambiar el tipo de dato de la tabla<sup>1</sup>.

Utilizé "`CAST (EntryNo AS NVARCHAR(50))`", pero me retorna este valor:

> 2.43586e+006

Y necesito retornarlo así:

> 2435864

¿Cómo puedo retornar el valor correctamente?

---

<sup>1</sup> Esta columna mas adelante será modificada para que guarde valores alfanuméricos, pero, aún no realizo este cambio = este cambio afectaría el funcionamiento actual.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas un float para representar un entero? En todo caso, si conviertes a un entero, y luego haces el cast a nvarchar, debería funcionar como esperas.  Te dejo un enlace con algunas opciones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation.

Comment: @sstan este campo viene de un Excel - *hice una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/103141/78) que tiene que ver con este proyecto*. La historia corta es que el valor de este campo no puede estar repetido y, para evitar duplicados, se debe concatenar otros caracteres, pero usando este número. Ejemplo `REC-2435864-1`. Esto no es problema, pero quiero que el SELECT me retorne por ahora el número pero como nvarchar. Ando corriendo con esto :\

Comment: Entiendo. Pero, en este momento, ¿puedes asumir que todos los valores en ese campo son enteros, o no?

Comment: @sstan si, por ahora si. Voy a cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna, pero, para efectos de esta pregunta, si tienes una respuesta la puedes colocar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar un `CAST` intermedio a un entero:

```
CAST(CAST(EntryNo AS BIGINT) AS NVARCHAR(50))
```

Por supuesto, esto asume que todos los valores son en realidad enteros, a pesar del tipo `FLOAT`. Pero como dices que ese es tu caso, debería funcionar bien.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de la función [`SRT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql), donde recibe como parámetros el campo a convertir, la longitud y número de decimales. Cabe mencionar que está función está disponible a partir de la version 2008 de SQL Server.

```
SELECT LTRIM(STR(EntryNo, 10, 0))
```

Aquí puedes ver la [demostración](http://rextester.com/RHMQF60563).